# Neural Network Hidden Layer Input Size for this Tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am following part 5 of this tutorial which can be found in in this link: http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/neural_network_implementation_part05/

This creates a neural network suitable for identification handwritten digits from 0-9.

In the middle of the tutorial, the author explains that the neural network has 64 inputs (representing the 64 pixel image) which contains two hidden neural networks that has a input size of 20. (see below screenshot)

[image]

I have two questions:

1) Can anyone explain the choice of projecting the 64 input layer onto a 20 input layer? Why the choice of 20? Is it arbitrary or determined by experiment? Is there an intuitive reason why?

2) Why two hidden layers? I read somewhere that most problems can be solved with 1-2 hidden layers, and that is usually determined by trial and error. Is it the same case here?

Appreciate any thoughts

Comment: while writing up an answer I found this amazing resource: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Comment: I've also read this answer before but I wanted an answer specifically for this tutorial. But I guess what you're saying is that the choice is likely very arbitrary

Comment: yes! arbitrary but sensible.

Comment: Your questions can both be answered by; what works best. The author most likely chose some random (but sensible!) amount of hidden neurons and layers. He chose whatever worked best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network has:

- one input layer with 64 neurons --> one for each pixel
- a hidden layer with 20 neurons
- another hidden layer with 20 neurons
- an output layer with 10 neurons --> one for each digit

The choice of two hidden layers with 20 neurons each is relatively arbitrary, and probably determined by experiment, just as you said. Also, the description of each of these layers as another *network* can be confusing/misleading. You are also right on account of 1-2 hidden layers usually being sufficient for problems, and with digit recognition, which is not to complex, this is the case.